# Children of Converts and Specific halachos

Tags: halacha, marriage, conversion-to-judaism, family-members, genealogy

The Pri Megadim in OC Siman 156 Ashel Avraham Sif-Katan 2 writes that a child that was conceived in kedusha (sanctity) and born in kedusha to a mother and father that had both converted (i.e. these 2 people converted then got married and had together a child -- the conception and birth taking place after the conversion) it's "mistavra" (makes sense to him) that that child is still called a "ger" (convert) since they don't have any Jewish relatives.

However what examples can be found in the poskim where we see practically that the child of converts is "treated" differently than a Born Jew and instead like a convert. We find many instances where a convert is considered to be in a different category then that of a born Jew. Is the Pri Megadim saying the children would be treated in every instance like a "normal convert"?

One such place is what we know from SA Evan HaEzer Siman Siman 7 Sif 21 that a daughter of converts may not lichatchila marry a Kohen (unless one of the parents is not a convert or after a few generations have past.) See this [question and answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14228/can-the-child-of-two-converts-marry-a-cohen) for more on this topic.

Are there any other similar examples that the child of converts has specific halachos related only to them?

(We see however from this halacha in Evan HaEzer that they are not considered to be like a "convert" mamash -- not like the Pri Megadim. A Cohen that marries a convert their sons would be considered be challelim and their daughters would not be allowed to marry Kohanim. In the case of a child of converts marrying a Kohen it's only a din lichatchila and not b'dieved.)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16815/759

Answer (score 2):

Kesuvos 4:3 says that the halachos of a Motzi Shem Ra vary depending on when the child of a convert was conceived and born:

> הַגִּיּוֹרֶת שֶׁנִּתְגַּיְּרָה בִתָּהּ עִמָּהּ, וְזִנְּתָה, הֲרֵי זוֹ בְּחֶנֶק. אֵין לָהּ לֹא פֶתַח בֵּית הָאָב, וְלֹא מֵאָה סָלַע. הָיְתָה הוֹרָתָהּ שֶׁלֹּא בִקְדֻשָּׁה וְלֵדָתָהּ בִּקְדֻשָּׁה, הֲרֵי זוֹ בִסְקִילָה. אֵין לָהּ לֹא פֶתַח בֵּית הָאָב וְלֹא מֵאָה סָלַע. הָיְתָה הוֹרָתָהּ וְלֵדָתָהּ בִּקְדֻשָּׁה, הֲרֵי הִיא כְבַת יִשְׂרָאֵל לְכָל דָּבָר.
>
> A woman who converted with her daughter, and [the daughter] committed adultery, she receives Chenek. She is not killed at her father's house, nor is there a 100 sela fine. If she was conceived before her mother's conversion and was born after, she receives Skilah, but she is not killed at her father's house, nor is there a 100 sela fine. If she was conceived and born after her mother's conversion, she is like a Bas Yisrael for everything.