# Must we show the children of coverts extra love?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

The Torah commands us to love converts: ואהבתם את הגר ([Ekev 10:19](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9974#v=19))

Are the children of converts considered "converts" in this context, or are they considered normal Jews?

Comment: Where does it say that we need to love them more?

Comment: possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22222/759

Comment: Like TrustMe said, where does it say we need to love converts? Please [edit] your question to clarify and provide context.

Comment: i did. its printed in every chumash!

Comment: The passuk you quoted doesn't convey that we ought to give converts _extra love_... It's just that we are to love them. We are commanded to love our fellow Jew, also: ואהבת לרעך כמוך (Vayikra 19:18)

Comment: i qouted a possuk in the torah. please refer there and understand that it means extra love. see also rambam and other commentaries that go to great length on this

Answer (score 5):

The Talmud, [Sanhedrin 94a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=94&format=pdf), has a discussion about what "VaYichad Yitro" ([Shemot 18:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9879#showrashi=true&v=10)) means. Shmuel says (as Rashi explains) that it means that he was very pained by the news of the downfall of Egypt. Rav (or Rav Pappa) says that this is what the people mean when they say that a convert, even up to 10 generations after the conversion, you should not disparage and Aramean in his presence.

> היינו דאמרי אינשי גיורא עד עשרה דרי לא תבזה ארמאי קמיה

Literal translation:

> This is the popular saying, "A convert, until 10 generations, do not disparage an Aramean in his presence."

So we see that even the descendant of a convert called a convert in this case, and requires extra sensitivity.