# What are the restrictions or unqualifications placed on a גר but not on a born jew?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism

What are the restrictions or unqualifications placed on a ger but not on a born jew?

Comment: Why do you think there are any?

Comment: @DannySchoemann I have heard it say that a ger can not serve in a beit din, but i don't know the source, and decided to leave it out of the question.

Comment: That is true - but it's not a "restriction" on the Ger, they are simply not qualified, similar to women, children and slaves. Source: Rambam הלכות סנהדרין Ch. 2. They also cannot be kings - (ibid הלכות מלכים ומלחמותיהם) - (All this in משנה תורה - ספר שופטים  - http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02038.html)

Comment: @DannySchoemann according to the Daf Yomi "Sanhedrin 57a-b: Abortion and Jewish Law", if a non-Jew were to abort an unborn fetus it would fall under the category of murder but not for a Jew. Is this the same for a Ger, if he were to abort an unborn fetus, it would be murder, but not so for a born Jew?

Comment: No! A Ger has the same Halacha as a Jew, he's just a 4th class citizen if we define 1st class as Cohen, 2nd as Levi, 3rd as born-Jewish. Some public positions require a certain class as a qualification. But he has the same obligations, punishements and responsibilities as everybody else - because a Ger is 100% Jewish.

Comment: @DannySchoemann why do you not make a class of king's and Kohen godol, and talmid chacham?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16813/759

Comment: @hazoriz I wouldn't count talmid chacham separately since anyone can become one.

Comment: @hazoriz For those sorts of questions you’d have to refer to the end of Horayos, which indicates that a Kohen Gadol isn’t necessarily better than a Kohen, nor is a Talmud Chachamim necessarily better than a Kohen. Though I’m not sure how I feel about being called a second-class citizen... :)

Comment: @DonielF can you please put a link to Horayos.

Comment: @ninamag http://Sefaria.org/Mishnah_Horayot.3.8. Read carefully and you’ll notice that a Ger is actually a sixth-class citizen. The Gemara there explains the order.

Comment: @DonielF Indeed. כֹּהֵן קוֹדֵם לְלֵוִי, לֵוִי לְיִשְׂרָאֵל, יִשְׂרָאֵל לְמַמְזֵר, וּמַמְזֵר לְנָתִין, וְנָתִין לְגֵר, וְגֵר לְעֶבֶד מְשֻׁחְרָר

Comment: But read the Gemara closely - it’s discussing whose life to save first. Who can serve as a judge is discussed elsewhere.